# Laravel translation not working

Tags: laravel, localization, translation

I have languages for french and english. Fallback and standard is french (fr).

My folder structure:
[image]

This is the content of the login.php (english):

```
<?php
return [
    'welcome' => 'Welcome',
    'mail' => 'E-Mail address',
    'password' => 'Password'
];
```

I am referencing the keys either using `@lang()` or `{{ trans('') }}`. Example:

```
<label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">{{ trans('admin.login.mail') }}</label>
```

However this gets returned as:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're putting language files into subfolder, you need to specify it using slash. So, try this instead:

```
{{ trans('admin/login.mail') }}
```

Comment: Oh... this works nicely. However I was already using dots for `trans()` on another project (5.1 or 5.2). It worked fine there, is this something new?

Comment: In Laravel 9 the translations weren't working. According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#introduction), the new default folder is `app/lang`. This doesn't seem to be true. However, when I moved the translation files (both .php & .json) to the usual path `app/resources/lang` the translations work! Can anyone explain why?

Comment: @Pathros I got the same issue and just figured out that Laravel will find the `lang` folder in `resources\lang` first, if the folder is not found, then it uses the directory `app/lang`. If you want to use files in `app\lang`, just delete folder `resources\lang`