# Laravel localization-translation doesn't work, shows only default language

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I'm trying to build multilingual website with laravel but there is a problem with translation. It shows only default language. Even if I set the app locale language, laravel continue to shows default language

when I said `app.test/ar/admin` or `app.test/en/admin`, routes and others works as well, I can reach the view, just trans message not work..

admin blade

```
<div class="row">
   <h1>{{trans('admin.welcome')}}</h1>
</div>
```

I tried with `__('admin.welcome')` but still same result..

app service provider;

```
public function boot(Request $request)
    {
        if (!session()->has("locale")) {
            session()->put("locale", $request->getPreferredLanguage(config("translatable.locales")));
        }
        app()->setLocale(session()->get("locale"));
    }
```

route service provider

```
 Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => session()->get("locale"),
        ], function ($router) {...});
```

language middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!in_array($request->segment(1), config('translatable.locales'))) {
            $segments = $request->segments();
            $segments = array_prepend($segments, app()->getLocale());
            return redirect()->to(implode('/', $segments));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

folder structure

```
--en
    +admin.php
    +auth.php
    +pagination.php
    +passwords.php
    +validation.php

--ar
    +admin.php
    +auth.php
    +pagination.php
    +passwords.php
    +validation.php
```

so how can I fix this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: php artisan cache:clear  -- run the command and check, it may cache. And also check  App::getLocale() return in the controller?

Comment: @Kool-Mind I tried it before :( doesn't work

Comment: ok, u will be sorted with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153529/laravel-translation-not-working

Comment: @Kool-Mind no sub folder case, all files under the language folder

Comment: which version of laravel is  this?

Comment: @Kool-Mind it's 5.6

Comment: can u try {{ trans('admin/welcome') }} ? Can u post your folder structure than better to know the issue.

Comment: @Kool-Mind I edited my question